# Is there a way to cache nightly and stable builds separately in Rust?

Tags: build, rust, rust-cargo

I am developing a Rust project and frequently do the following commands in series:

```
# runs clippy on latest nightly
rustup run nightly cargo clippy
# run tests on stable
cargo test
```

This causes my project to rebuild the full set of dependencies every time I build each. Is there a way to cache the builds separately?

Comment: thanks for the dup tag, I wasn't thinking of looking up "parallel"!